# Wall outlets with constant power

Tags: electrical

All my wall outlets through out the house have constant power whether the switches are on or off. What can I do to make the power to the outlets be controlled by the switches? Jake

Comment: You'd have to rewire the circuit, so that the "hot" conductor was connected to the switch before going to any of the receptacles  (probably not practical).  Or buy combination switch/receptacle devices, and wire them so that the switch controls the receptacle (probably not practical).

Comment: Where are you? In the US the normal arrangement is that all, or nearly all, of the receptacles are powered without being switched.

Answer (score 2):

In this day and age? Use smart switches and either smart outlets or modules that the lamp plugs into.

But for God's sake, don't omit the permanently installed light - that should still be switched by a switch.  (It can be a second switch).  "Switched outlets instead of an installed lights" is **not a style**. They want you to think that, but it's just to save a couple bucks at the expense of safety.

Because real world, it's confusing whether you turn that plug-in light *at the lamp* or *at the switch*, and people do the wrong thing a lot, leaving them stumbling in the dark.  It's much worse for guests and **First Responders**.  I've seen several EMT interventions where they were flummoxed by light switches that did nothing. Disgraceful in the LED age.

Answer (score 1):

To have a switched outlet the wiring is going to need to be changed. Running a pair of new new wires to a switch and changing the wiring to the outlet to interrupt the hot leg when the switch is off. Depending on how the home was wired this could knock out all the outlets in a room plus other rooms. The common practice is to break the hot side tab on the outlet feed a switch with the hot and then return the switched hot to the other side of the outlet. This creates a single outlet controlled by the switch and the second outlet and others in the chain are still hot.

Comment: An alternative would be to use wireless receptacles that go in the wall and don't require any wiring changes. GE, for example, makes a line of Z-wave, [in-wall outlet](http://www.zwaveproducts.com/shop/brands/ge/z-wave-in-wall-smart-duplex-outlet)s and switches.